# View doesn't appear before time consuming operation

Tags: ios, swift

I've implemented this indicator in my app: https://github.com/vincechan/SwiftLoadingIndicator

Right after this loading spinner comes to front, I want it to spin all the time, for as long as my operation lasts.

In my operation I do some work on images and then show them to the user, but everytime after I click the "run operation" button, app freezes for a few seconds, updates view with the results and then shows the overlay spinner.
I've tried async dispatch like this:

```
 @IBAction func manipulateImage(sender: AnyObject) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    LoadingOverlayView.show()
                }); 
       if let beginImage = CIImage(image: self.imageView.image!) {
                    var outputImage = OutputImage(sourceImage: beginImage)
    //apply CIFilters:
                    outputImage.applyFilter(FilterType.Grayscale)
                    outputImage.applyFilter(FilterType.Sepia)
                    outputImage.applyFilter(FilterType.Vignette)
                    outputImage.applyFilter(FilterType.Shadow)

                    let cgimg = self.imageContext.createCGImage(outputImage, fromRect: outputImage.extent)

                    self.imageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: cgimg)
    LoadingOverlayView.hide()
}
```

but it doesn't work. Also normal method calls, without async dispatch, acts exactly the same.

Comment: You are going to need to show more code than that. Where is this code getting called? Where are you hiding the `LoadingOverlayView`?

Comment: @AdamPro13 I've updated the post with pretty much eveything I have in there.

Comment: Are you running it on the main thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely running this code on the UI thread.  If so you can dispatch the operation to a background queue as follows:

```
// we're already on the UI thread, so dispatch to a background queue
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
   // do your background operations ...
   if let beginImage = CIImage(image: self.imageView.image!) {
       var outputImage = OutputImage(sourceImage: beginImage)
       //apply CIFilters:
       outputImage.applyFilter(FilterType.Grayscale)
       outputImage.applyFilter(FilterType.Sepia)
       outputImage.applyFilter(FilterType.Vignette)
       outputImage.applyFilter(FilterType.Shadow)

       let cgimg = self.imageContext.createCGImage(outputImage, fromRect: outputImage.extent)

       // make sure to dispatch UI function back to main queue!
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
               self.imageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: cgimg)

                LoadingOverlayView.hide()
            }); 
     }
});

// we're already on the UI thread, so show the overlay now
LoadingOverlayView.show()
```

Comment: It's pretty much what I want but there's this log: `This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.` I guess we should get rid of it.

Comment: You're being warned about doing UI operations on a background thread, do heed this warning.  Please see the note in the code about dispatching UI operations back to the main queue (e.g. your overlay hide op).